# Binary file- menu writing and reading, in c issue

Tags: c, file, menu, binary

I have to write a program for writing and reading a binary file. There should be a menu for the choice. The file should have indentification number, an article with name, parameters, etc and a price. So it has to be int|sizeof char|char|double.

I have some issues with the code. It compiles. I open the file and write in it. But it "dont want" to read itself. When I remove the double slash comments to make the check the program prints the errors. I need help.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writing();
void reading();
int main ()
{
    char choice;

    /* do
    {
        printf("Enter 1 for writening in file and 2 for reading!\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
       // choice=getchar();
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(choice!='1'&&choice!='2');
    switch(choice)
    {
        case '1':writing(); break;
        case '2':reading(); break;
    } */

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        printf("Choose 1 for writening and 2 for reading\n");
       //choice=getchar();
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        fflush(stdin);
       if (choice=='1'||choice=='2')
       break;
    }
        switch(choice)
        {

        case '1': writing (); break;
        case '2': reading (); break;
        }


    return 0;
}
void writing ()
{
    int j,i; // size of article
    int number;
    char article[50];
    double price;

    FILE*fp;

    printf("Enter a string less than 50\n");
    gets(article);

    //scanf("%c", &article);

    j=(sizeof (article));

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("Enter a price:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &price);

    if (fp=fopen ("writing.data","ab")==NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldnt open the file\n");
    }

    fwrite(&number,sizeof (int),1,fp);

   /* if(fwrite(&number,sizeof (int),1,fp)!=1)
    {
       printf("Error\n");
    } */
    fwrite(&j,sizeof(int),1,fp);

    /* if(fwrite(&j,sizeof (int),1,fp)!=1)
    {
       printf("Error\n");
    } */
      fwrite(article,sizeof (article),1,fp);

    /*  if(fwrite(article,sizeof (article),1,fp)!=1)
    {
       printf("Error\n");
    } */

    fwrite(&price,sizeof (double),1,fp);

    /*if(fwrite(&price,sizeof (double),1,fp)!=1)
    {
       printf("Error\n");
    } */

    fclose(fp);
}

void reading()
{
    int i; // size of article
    int number;
    int number1;
    char article[50];
    double price;

    FILE*fp;

    printf("Enter a number to start the reading:");
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    if (fp=fopen ("writing.data","rb")==NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldnt open the file\n");
    }
    for (;;)
    {
       fread(&number,sizeof(int),1,fp);

      /*  if(fread(&number,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1)
        {
            printf("Error");
            break;
        } */

        fread(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp);

       /* if(fread(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        } */

        fread(article,sizeof(article),1,fp);

       /* if(fread(article,sizeof(article),1,fp)!=1)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(2);
        } */

        fread(&price,sizeof (double),1,fp);

        /* if(fread(&price,sizeof (double),1,fp)!=1)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(3);
        } */

        if(number==number1)
        {
            printf("%d", number);
            printf(article);
            printf("%lf", price);

        }
}
 fclose(fp);

}
```

Ok, so i edited the parenthesis and it works. But without the checks. Thats the reason i commended them. It seems i have problem with them, can u give me more info about the checks in C and help me get these ones work.
These are the warnings [warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STbmd.jpg)

*Edit2
I typed the code from the zero again and it works. I fixed the checks.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
if (fp=fopen ("writing.data","rb")==NULL)
```

You forgot to place the parenthesis corretly. Replace it by:

```
if ((fp=fopen ("writing.data","rb"))==NULL)
```

Compile with all warnings enabled and your compiler should give you a warning.

There are other issues, for example:

```
if ((fp=fopen ("writing.data","rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldnt open the file\n");
    // you should exit here, it's pointless to continue
}
...
```

If you continue execution when `fp` is `NULL`, you end up with an `fread` where the file pointer is `NULL` which leads to undefined behaviour (most likely your program will crash).

Comment: `if (fp=fopen ("writing.data","ab")==NULL)`  That's a perfect example of why trying to do too much in one line of code is a bad idea.  Two lines such as `fp=fopen("writing.data","ab"); if (fp==NULL)...` is easier to understand and *much* less bug-prone.